# OpenCV on Devkit8000

Tags: opencv, devkit

I am using devkit8000 for my robotic application. I want to port OpenCV on devkit. Can anybody tell me the procedure to port OpenCV on devkit8000.
I have already done the system(linux) development and customization for the board.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This question is better suited to the OpenCV mailing list.

Nevertheless, I think you can installed the beagleboard port with: `opkg install opencv`

If that doesn't work, you can start reading the [wiki page on how to set up a system to do image processing with a BeagleBoard](http://www.hbrobotics.org/wiki/index.php5/Beagle_Board).